# Inertial frame of reference, i have specific and different questions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, definition

I HAVE TWO QUERIES

1. see in inertial frame of reference, Newton's laws are valid but acceleration  of body is not included, but Newton's second law itself  includes acceleration then when Newton's second law itself includes acceleration concept, then how we can apply Netwon's law to inertial frame of reference, where acceleration is not included?
2. inertial frame of reference  is just as some coordinate system? Iam not getting what exactly it is?

Comment: What research have you done?   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference

Answer (score 1):

1. an inertial reference frame is one in which the reference frame itself is not accelerating. There is no restriction on the motion of objects with respect to the inertial frame.
2. a reference frame can either mean a coordinate system or a vierbein or a physical set of clocks and rulers. Different authors use the term differently, so it is important to understand how an individual author is using the term and not assume one single usage